# How to connect to memcached server from outside?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memcached

I installed memcached on AWS EC2 Ubuntu, and I can connect it by `telnet` in the server:

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

But how can I connect it from other machine? I know the interval ip is 172.31.17.208, but when I try to connect it from another EC2 by:

```
telnet 172.31.17.208 11211
```

the response is

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 11211: connect failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a **Public IP/ Elastic IP** if you want to access your Memcache from outside of the AWS.

Your internal IP will work within the VPC and not outside of your VPC. I am guessing the another instance that you are trying to access is not in the same VPC. Try pinging your Memcache server from another instance and check if it is resolved using internal IP.

**Edit:**

Apart from this, you might need to check your security group and make sure the ports are open for incoming connection.

Comment: Yes I can ping from the other instance and it is resolved using internal IP.

Comment: Have you check you security group to see if port is open for connection?

Comment: You are right, I need to open a rule in the security group.

Comment: @JeffTian if it was helpful you can mark as answer :)